# How to connect a HTML page to MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

How to connect a html page to MySQL for example, i want to use `<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>` in a HTML file. How do i connect to MySQL. 
I have tryed this:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("HOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("DATABASE"); 
?>
```

But it did not work.

Comment: MySQL isn't required for `$_POST`.

Comment: Well, for a start, this is PHP, not HTML, you can't connect to MySQL using HTML. Secondly, using $_POST variables doesn't require a connection to MySQL, you could quite happily do `echo $_POST['username']` without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML are markup languages, basically they are set of tags like `<html>, <body>,` which is used to present a website using css, and javascript as a whole. All these, happen in the clients system or the user you will be browsing the website.

Now, Connecting to a database, happens on whole another level. It happens on server, which is where the website is hosted.

So, in order to connect to the database and perform various data related actions, you have to use server-side scripts, like php, jsp, asp.net etc.

Now, lets see a snippet of connection using MYSQLi Extension of PHP

```
$db = mysqli_connect('hostname','username','password','databasename');
```

This single line code, is enough to get you started, you can mix such code, combined with HTML tags to create a HTML page, which is show data based pages. For example:

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('hostname','username','password','databasename');
?>
<html>
    <body>
          <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM `mytable`;";
                $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                      // Display your datas on the page
                }
          ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

In order to insert new data into the database, you can use phpMyAdmin or write a INSERT query and execute them.

Comment: Yes except for this is a terrible practice, putting database calls in the view layer.  You should separate your code so that one layer handles persistence, one handles business logic, one handles presentation logic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this in html page, you need to write the code in a PHP file and save it on a server then execute it.

NOTE : mysql_* functions are deprecated, you should use the newer mysqli_* or PDO features of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it on a server not just in a browser.

Download Apache, Install PHP and save the file with a `.php` extension. It then should work.

Then you can echo out a `$_POST` value but you wont need SQL for that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot add whatever PHP code to an HTML page. it have to be a PHP page.
2. you don't need a mysql connection to echo $_POST['username']
3. you should never echo any $_POST variable. After processing a POST request, web-server **ought** to order the browser to reload the page using GET method. Not required for the AJAX calls though.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't too sure about that one too.

Comment: I think what he means by point 3 is, if you don't do a redirect after a successful POST, then the user presses reload in the browser, it will re-POST the data.  If you use a redirect then if they do a reload, it just reloads the "thank you" page or wherever it redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run PHP scripts in HTML files. Your file must have `.php` extension to run php scripts.

You should use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of `mysql_` functions, because these functions are depricated!

Comment: Not strictly true ;), they don't have *have* to be `.php` files if you don't want them to be.

Comment: PDO it have to be. mysqli is unusable with prepared statements (which are main reason to move)

Comment: I know you can set any file on htaccess to run like a php file, but he surely don't know.. He must know how to start using php

Answer (score 0):

Of course it should not work because html is client side and you are doing connection at server side so you might need a something great called server-side scripting language to accomplish your task.

How ever you can still do it in html page with ajax but as i said you has to use server-side scripting language.